# Getting problem in removing end slash from directory

Tags: htaccess

this is my code but i tried many ways but it is not working and i am not able to remove the end slash from the directory

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# remove enter code here.php; use THE_REQUEST to prevent infinite loops
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]

# remove index
RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=301]

# remove slash if not directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]

# add .php to access file, but don't redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

# Remove trailing slashes
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This will happen because you are removing the tailing slash and then expecting it to be added for directories, I don't think this will work and the work around would be to remove everything referring to adding a slash and use **[mod_autoindex.html](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html)**

That way you can have `/directory/index.html` that will be processed without the tailing slash so this would look like `/directory` and still list your files as directory view. Quick and easy work around while maintaining the same URL structor of the rest of the site.